# Как тестировать обобщённый (generic) метод?

Tags: java, generics, junit

Имеется статический метод `getPatches(Object, Object)` в публичном классе `JsonUtil` который тестируется с помощью JUnit 4.12 на Eclipse 2021-09:

```java
import javax.annotation.Nonnull;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.type.TypeReference;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;

public static List<PatchOperation> getPatches(
    @Nonnull Object oldData,
    @Nonnull Object newData)
    throws IOException
{
    List<PatchOperation> _patchOperations = new ArrayList<>();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    String _oldDataJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(oldData);
    String _newDataJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(newData);

    JsonNode _oldJsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(_oldDataJson);
    JsonNode _newJsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(_newDataJson);

    JsonNode _patchData = com.github.fge.jsonpatch.diff.JsonDiff.asJson(_oldJsonNode, _newJsonNode);
    if (_patchData != null)
    {
        _patchOperations = objectMapper.convertValue(_patchData, new TypeReference<List<PatchOperation>>(){});
    }

    return _patchOperations;
}
```

Здесь, `PatchOperation` просто POJO класс для де/-сериализации [JSON-Patch](http://jsonpatch.com/) (см. [RFC6902](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6902)), который используется в [PATCH-запросах](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc5789) к серверу:

```java
import java.io.Serializable;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonIgnoreProperties;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonProcessingException;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class PatchOperation implements Serializable
{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 9999999999999999999L;
    
    @JsonProperty("op")
    public String Operation;
    
    @JsonProperty("path")
    public String Path;
    
    @JsonProperty("value")
    public Object Value;
    
    @JsonProperty("from")
    public String From;
    
    @Override
    public String toString() 
    {
        try
        {
            return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(this);
        }
        catch ( JsonProcessingException e )
        {
            return super.toString();
        }
    }
}
```

JUnit тест для метода `getPatches`:

```java
@Test public final void getPatchesTest()
            throws JsonProcessingException, IOException
{
    PatchTestItem _itemOne = new PatchTestItem();
    _itemOne.id = "ABC123";
    _itemOne.active = true;
    _itemOne.value = "First value";

    PatchTestItem _itemTwo = new PatchTestItem();
    _itemTwo.id = "ABC123";
    _itemTwo.active = true;
    _itemTwo.value = "Updated value";

    java.util.List<PatchOperation> _patches = JsonUtil.getPatches(_itemOne, _itemTwo);

    Assert.assertNotNull(_patches);
    Assert.assertEquals(1, _patches.size());
    // в следующей строке выбрасывает ошибку при тестировании обобщённого метода
    Assert.assertEquals("replace", _patches.get(0).Operation);
    Assert.assertEquals("/value", _patches.get(0).Path);
    Assert.assertEquals(_itemTwo.value, _patches.get(0).Value.toString());
    
    _itemTwo.value = _itemOne.value;
    _patches = JsonUtil.getPatches(_itemOne, _itemTwo);
    
    Assert.assertNotNull(_patches);
    Assert.assertEquals(0, _patches.size());
    
    _itemTwo.active = false;
    _itemTwo.value = "Updated value again";
    _patches = JsonUtil.getPatches(_itemOne, _itemTwo);
    
    Assert.assertNotNull(_patches);
}
```

Тест выполняется и в таком виде всё нормально.
Теперь было решено использовать обобщённый метод следующим образом:

```java
public static <T> List<T> getPatches(
    @Nonnull Object oldData,
    @Nonnull Object newData)
    throws IOException
{
    List<T> _patchOperations = new ArrayList<>();
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();

    String _oldDataJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(oldData);
    String _newDataJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(newData);

    JsonNode _oldJsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(_oldDataJson);
    JsonNode _newJsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(_newDataJson);

    JsonNode _patchData = com.github.fge.jsonpatch.diff.JsonDiff.asJson(_oldJsonNode, _newJsonNode);
    if (_patchData != null)
    {
        _patchOperations = objectMapper.convertValue(_patchData, new TypeReference<List<T>>(){});
    }

    return _patchOperations;
}
```

Вышеприведённый вариант не проходит тест - выдаёт ошибку "Source not found" и в лог вываливается:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.LinkedHashMap cannot be cast to xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.PatchOperation
    at xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.JsonUtilTest.getPatchesTest(JsonUtilTest.java:36)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:93)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:40)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:529)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:756)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:452)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:210)
```

Я конечно понимаю, что проблема заключается в том, что JUnit не может найти тип, но как и что мне изменить, чтоб тест выполнялся?

Comment: `JsonUtilTest.java:36` это что за строчка в тесте?

Comment: Проблема в этом месте `objectMapper.convertValue(_patchData, new TypeReference<List<T>>(){})`. Тут в runtime у objectMapper нет информации о типе элемента в который, нужно конвертировать json. Т.е. он не знает, что нужно создавать объект типа `PatchOperation`. И он создает то, что может `LinkedHashMap`. Ну и потом уже проблема в тесте при попытке использовать объект как `PatchOperation`. У вас 100% есть warning-и компилятора (они то и говорят, что код небезопасный)

Comment: @RomanKonoval и что делать? как быть? Как передать "информацию о типе элемента"? Правильно ли я понимаю, что это никоим образом не связано с самим тестом? Или код метода при компиляции/дебаге будет работать?

Comment: Проблема не в тесте. Проблема в коде (выше я написал где именно). Можно ли jackson маперу передать информацию о типе динамически, я не знаю, нужно смотреть. Простой и тупой метод это передавать явно `TypeReference` аргументом в `getPatches`, так чтоб в месте вызова был точный тип: `JsonUtil.getPatches(_itemOne, _itemTwo, LIST_OF_PATCH_OPERATIONS_TYPE);` ну и определить константу `LIST_OF_PATCH_OPERATIOS_TYPE = new TypeReference<List<PatchOperation>>(){}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо Роману, за разъяснения и помощь. По предложению @RomanKonoval в метод был добавлен параметр, которым и передаётся требуемая информация о типе:

```java
public static <T> T getPatches(
    @Nonnull Object oldData,
    @Nonnull Object newData,
    final TypeReference<T> typeRef)
    throws IOException
{
    String _oldDataJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(oldData);
    String _newDataJson = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(newData);

    JsonNode _oldJsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(_oldDataJson);
    JsonNode _newJsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(_newDataJson);

    JsonNode _patchData = com.github.fge.jsonpatch.diff.JsonDiff.asJson(_oldJsonNode, _newJsonNode);
    return new ObjectMapper().convertValue(_patchData, typeRef);
}
// Пример использования:
// final TypeReference<List<PatchOperation>> _typeRef =
//       new TypeReference<List<PatchOperation>>() {};
// List<PatchOperation> _patches =
//       JsonUtil.getConvertedPatch(_itemOne, _itemTwo, _typeRef);
```

Буду рад конструктивной критике и замечаниям.